# How to automatically set height of slick carousel

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using the slick caurousel for test. I am currently hard coding the height of the slides:

```
<div class="slides">
    <div>slide a</div>
    <div>slide b</div>
    <div>slide c</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slides {
    height: 200px;
}
```

What I would like, though, is for the carousel to automatically be the hight of the tallest slide. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think the problem doing this, is that when you have images inside with an undefined height, you have to wait for them to be loaded and then set the height afterwards. And this could be visible for the user, like flickering ...

Answer (score 20):

```
$('.class').slick({
adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

Add the `adaptiveHeight` to set auto height of the image

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my case. My slides contain mainly text, which may be why. Perhaps `adaptiveHeight` only works for images?

Comment: Thanks! Woks for me)

Comment: Works for mee too,using text + images as content @Sam Lee!

Answer (score 3):

```
.slick-slide {
  height: 0px!important;
 }
 .slick-slide.slick-active {
    height: 100% !important;  
 }
```

Above CSS might help